# UI Router $stateParams are only readable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm currently passing in an id to a new state with $stateParams. Works fine, but what if the user reloads the page? Obviously, there will not be any values in $stateParams. The work around for this was to load the $stateParam id into localStorage on initial page load. On reload, if the id of $stateParams doesn't exist, then manually assign it. For example:

```
// Ensure params are set when page is reloaded
if (!$stateParams.id) {
  $stateParams.id = localStorageService.get('campaignId');
  $state.go($state.current, $stateParams);
}
```

On my local machine this works. However on my development server, I'm getting this error:

`Cannot assign to read only property 'id' of object '#<Object>'`.

Is there a way I can make $stateParams writable?

Hope this makes sense, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create a https://plnkr.co or https://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: There are some hacks to do it but in most cases this approach is a sign for some kind of bad design decision. You normally keep the state you need after a reload in the URL as a route param an then you use state.go() to set the stateParams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a solution to actually write to $stateParams, I just created a new object for this situation.

```
var stateParamsClone = {};
// Ensure params are set when page is reloaded
if (!$stateParams.id) {
  stateParamsClone.id = localStorageService.get('campaignId');
  $state.go($state.current, stateParamsClone);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

`let $stateParams = Object.assign({}, $transition$.params());`